# My SQL return always a 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query. However, it does not work properly. The echo returns always a 1, but there are 3 rows in the db

```
<?php
include "db_connect.inc.php";

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM profiles";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($num == 0) 
    echo "0";

echo $num;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` returns the number of rows in the result set, not the value of the first field in the first row.

Comment: your query returns **1** row with value **3**

Comment: So it shows one row only and does not show the count right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns **1** row with value **3**

To see what you do expect you need something like:

```
<?php
    include "db_connect.inc.php";
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) myCount FROM profiles";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['myCount'];
    } else {
      echo "0";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're doing an aggregate query, which means you'll ALWAYS get one row of results - one row containing the count() value you requested. Even if that count() is `0`, you'll STILL get one row of results.

If you want to check the value of the count, you have to fetch that row and check the field's value, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM profiles";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['cnt'] == 0) { die("No profiles"); }
```